# Beneficios de cerrar un cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite, optimización

Tengo una aplicación en la que uso Cursores para guardar los datos obtenidos de una consulta SQLite y en muchas ocasiones se me olvida cerrarlos `Cursor.close();`

¿Qué problemas me puede traer eso? ¿Me consume más memoria RAM en el dispositivo?

Si fuera así me compensaría recorrerme toda la app y cerrarlos todos pero si no tiene beneficios no tendré prisa para cerrarlos.

Comment: Lo indicado es cerrarlos, el principal beneficio es liberar recursos. Recuerdo un caso que tuve con una aplicación la cual en ocasiones se cerraba y no se encontraba el problema, primeramente cerré todos los cursores (no estaba cerrado ninguno), encontré que en ocasiones se realizaban determinadas operaciones las cuales mantenían en memoria los valores de ciertos campos y provocaban que funcionara la aplicación, pero si no se realizaba esa secuencia de operaciones, simplemente los datos requeridos no se encontraban y provocaban fallo en la aplicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagina una aplicación donde requieres varias operaciones DAO para realizar la lectura de datos, si estos cursores no son cerrados los datos se permanecerían en memoria.

```
    public List<Articulo> obtenerArticulos() {
    ...
    ...
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Articulos.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,  null, Articulos.POSICION + DESC);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ...
            articulos.add(articulo);
        }
        cursor.close(); // * Importante cerrar el cursor creado por cada operación!.
        return articulos;
    }
```

La [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) te indica sobre el método [close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close())

> **Cierra el cursor, liberando todos los recursos y haciendo la instancia
>   invalida.**

Al cerrar el cursor se liberan recursos, creo que es el beneficio más importante el cual responde a tu pregunta.

Comment: Esto me ha resuelto mi duda completamente, pero me hecho tener otras... por ejemplo:

Comment: Antes pulse Enter sin querer y se envió xD bueno la pregunta era si sentencias como break; en un switch cierran los cursores que hay dentro.

Comment: Me da gusto te ayudara mi respuesta  borjis. Lo único que cierra cursores es llamar el metodo .close() del cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre he leído que es muy recomendable cerrarlos ya que te puede provocar una pérdida de memoria en tu aplicación (leak memory).

Aunque depende del método que estés usando para generar tu cursor. Si usas el método [`managedQuery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String))(deprecated en la API 11) no necesitarás usarlo ya que te lo cierra el automáticamente. Como indica la documentación de Android:

> **Warning**: Do not call close() on a cursor obtained using this method, because the activity will do that for you at the appropriate time. However, if you call stopManagingCursor(Cursor) on a cursor from a managed query, the system will not automatically close the cursor and, in that case, you must call close().

lo que viene a decir que este método te cerrará el cursor en el momento apropiado y que en caso de que uses el método `stopManagingCursor(Cursor)` (también deprecated en API 11) si que necesitas cerrarlo.

Como te recomienda la documentación de Android, utiliza [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) como sustitución (en caso de que estés usando alguno de los métodos anteriores).